# could not deduce from a use of "color"

Tags: haskell, opengl, glut

I got a "could not deduce" error when I try to call color in GLUT.

```
Could not deduce (ColorComponent Float)
  arising from a use of ‘color’
from the context (RealFloat a, VertexComponent a)
  bound by the inferred type of
           drawVert :: (RealFloat a, VertexComponent a) => Vertex2 a -> IO ()
  at double.hs:(39,1)-(40,24)
In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘color’
In the expression: color . getcolor
In a stmt of a 'do' block: color . getcolor $ mandel v
```

Here is my code:

```
import Graphics.UI.GLUT
import Control.Monad
import Data.Int
import Data.Complex
drawVert v = do color . getcolor $ mandel v
                vertex v
mandel (Vertex2 r i) = length . takeWhile (\z -> magnitude z <= 2) .
                       take iterations $ iterate (\z -> z^2 + (r :+ i)) 0
getcolor :: Int -> Color3 Float
getcolor iter | iter == iterations = color3 0 0 0
              | otherwise          = color3 (amt*0.5) amt (amt*0.5)
              where amt = iter // iterations
```

I suspect that both the OpenGL and GLUT contain color, and haskell doesn't know which it should use. But how to solve that?

Comment: What if you add `import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GL.VertexSpec()`

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: You must use [`GLfloat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenGL-3.0.2.0/docs/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-GL-VertexSpec.html#t:ColorComponent) which has an instance (`Float` doesn't).